# How can I use the Lucene WikipediaTokenizer for non-English languages?

Tags: parsing, lucene, wikipedia

I'm a parsing the Dutch WikiPedia and it contains the following category markup:

```
[Categorie:Nederlands beeldhouwer]]
```

However the English Wikipedia uses the following markup:

```
[[Category:Japanese diplomats]]
```

The markup (Categorie/Category) is thus language dependent. Is it possible to use the [Lucene WikipediaTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/wikipedia/WikipediaTokenizer.html) for non-English wikis? If possible, how?

Answer (score 0):

I think wikipedia markups are language dependent, API results also will be different by languages.

As per http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API I did quick experiment with same query and got different results for http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php and http://nl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

LuceneWikipediaTokenizer is extension of StandardTokenizer thus it should support and index all languages.